# (PDFBox) java.awt.print.PrinterException: Printer is not accepting job

Tags: java, printing, pdfbox

this is a bug that I cannot even reproduce in our test environments - as of yet it happens only in production and it takes some time of running to occur (after a restart it's ok for a while).

While printing PDF files the aforementioned exception gets thrown and in the printer queue I can see the job hanging with an error status. What bugs me a bit is that the files I print are about 40 kb size and the print queue shows them as around 1.4 MB but maybe it's normal, I don't know. Anyway, I read a thing or two about this exception, but something is not quite right - the application uses Java version 1.7.0_02 and also I cannot read PrinterState and PrinterStateReasons from attributes. Actually, the only attributes are the following:

```
printer-is-accepting-jobs: not-accepting-jobs
color-supported: not-supported
queued-job-count: 5
printer-name: HP LaserJet P4010_P4510 Series PCL 6
```

Windows environment, the printer is accessed via print server. People on the other side of the wire claim that printing from other applications works alright.

What would be my best bet to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Well then.

Eventually I decided to use this workaround:
http://copy-con.blogspot.com/2009/12/printer-is-not-accepting-job.html

I had my serious doubts about deploying this to production, because it looks shifty as hell (like really, it basically means you're overwriting one of Java runtime classes), but seems like it was a good decision - the errors are gone (no wonder), the printer stopped choking and our client is happy.

Comment: While the link may be helpful, please at least offer a short summary here of what it is about.